# How to execute a function before someone click play button in audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want a function to be called just before play button is clicked.
A code which should work something like this :

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="music.mp3"/>
    <source src="music.ogg" />
</audio>

<script>
$('playbutton').on('click', function(e){
//some functions
});  
</script>
```

Comment: this is not clear what you are asking

Comment: just want to execute a function before play button triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Audio has onplay event.

```
<audio onplay="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for play and pause events.

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="music.mp3"/>
    <source src="music.ogg" />
</audio>

var audio = document.getElementById('audio')

audio.addEventListener('play', () => console.log('play'))
audio.addEventListener('pause', () => console.log('pause'))
```

[Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)